# Can I use TFS 2015 Express with Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs-2015

I need to migrate an old VSS 2005 source control database and I have downloaded & installed [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Express 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48259).

But I still have to use Visual Studio 2012 Professional (Reinstalled Team Explorer 2012 and then update 5). Trying to create a new project on TFS server throws error:

> TF30172: You are trying to create a team project either without
>   required permission or with  an older version of Team Explorer.

As I have added my account as TFS administrator I suppose the problem is with older version? Note that I have almost no experience with TFS, because I never needed it before. I cannot find any other means how to create a new project. (I planned to use [this wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612883(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Can I use TFS 2015 Express with Visual Studio 2012 Professional and if yes, how do I create a first empty project?

Comment: Adding a new project succeeded from VS 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, only the latest version has "full" compatibility with the latest Team Foundation Server. You have to use the same Visual Studio of visual studio as the version of TFS that you're connecting to to create a team project.

If you're using TFS 2015 Update 2 or later then you can create a team project from the web as well.

Useful links:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-TW/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project
- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements#client-compatibility

Comment: What means `Supports Git with Visual Studio Tools for Git extension.` - so it supports TFS configured with GIT repository?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 and later include Git tools by default. But in VS2012, if you want to use Git version control in TFS 2015, you need to install Visual Studio Tools for Git: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c

Comment: What would be the simplest repository to configure if I use it just myself for version control?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal, TFS supports two types of version control Git and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC). Git is the default version control provider for new projects. You should use Git for version control in your projects unless you have a specific need for centralized version control features in TFVC. Check https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc. By the way, since you are in a small team, you can use Visual Studio Team Service instead of TFS express. VSTS is free for 5 users, you can start test on website below: https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/.